# Here there are zero

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> memory of elevant: **in** time lanah sevenson fell down a threehouse. **here**fracture two the head? confusion nausea **are** **thir**sty but jolly **teen** sees **what** is still afive **?**

help

> in this hint are three

help

> in this one are two

help

> THINK YOU'RE CLEVER EH - IN THIS HINT THERE ARE ZERO

Comment: [...What?](http://i.imgur.com/fw1vI.jpg)

Comment: @EngineerToast "Puzzles where the genre or solving strategy of the puzzle is not explicitly stated; puzzles where the puzzler must deduce what type of puzzle it is."

Comment: There are a lot of numbers hidden in the text: eleven, seven, three, two, thirteen. 'Fracture' could be a mathematical term as well. My guess is, it is a kind of mathematical equation that we have to solve.

Comment: is it lanah? :P

Comment: From the bold text in the question, it clearly states:  "In here there are thirteen what?"  So obviously this is what we are meant to solve.

Answer (score 3):

this should work for the missing word assuming it is a missing word.

> indivisibility

the counts in the title and the hints are the numbers of lowercase i's in the statement. The statement already has 7 i's so the only word with 6 i's i can think of is that.

Also

> (7 + 3) / 2 is still 5 if there is also a need for the word to count towards a math operation.

Could also be

> dots

of which there are 13 in the statement with the punctuation and the j in addition to the i's

Comment: Since all the numbers hidden in it are prime, that word fits very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

the question is:

> in here are thirteen ____ (grey-ed out words)

and the answer is

> prime numbers. elevant, sevenson, threehouse, two, thirteen, afive,

Comment: you found a bunch of prime numbers! but that is not the solution to the puzzle

Answer (score 0):

To the wild-guess mobile!

> **Otto** (or some other thing that has two **t**s in it - **Toto**). Also it could be **tits** (yeah it's a bad word).

Why?

> Both hints refer to the number of **t**s in them.

So...

> There are 11 **t**s in the sentence and we need a word (possibly a name) that has two **t**s in order for **in here are thirteen ____**. That is why **tits** is also a good solution as it sort of sounds like **t**s.

Comment: I like how you interpreted the hints, but look at the title!

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the title.